# Siteminder response attribute script

Tags: attributes, response, siteminder

**Part One Question:**
We have an interesting situation at my workplace where the application developer wants to use two links to the same application, one for external and one for internal, to allow for segregation of internal and external user accounts.

The problem we are running into now is that when an external user is authenticated its not pulling down their user attribute from the HTTP header variable. We know the issue is that the internal users use `sAMAccountName` as the `userattr` and the external use `uid`as the `userattr`.

To get around this issue we want to use the custom script block, unless there is a better method to solve this, in order to check for `userattr="uid"`if `userattr="sAMAccountName"` is not present.

This is a sample of the language used in the custom script box:

```
`DR-USER_ID=<%userattr="sAMAccountName"%>` Internal user header check
`DR-USER_ID=<%userattr="uid"%>` External user header check
```

**Part two question:**
Probably the more important one, does anyone know if this is written in a specific language for this scriptlet? We were thinking it could be Perl but have not been able to confirm or deny this yet.

[image: Image showing the Modify Response Attribute screenshot where this script is being editted.]

Comment: What you've got there in that Script field is definitely not Perl.

Comment: That is the default script that is written by siteminder, thank you for identifying that it is not perl.

Comment: https://docops.ca.com/ca-single-sign-on/12-52-sp2/en/programming/programming-in-perl/perl-scripting-overview says you can do _something_ in Perl.

Comment: Yes this unfortunately has no tie ins with the scripting language used in the scriptlet box. I have confirmation from CA as well that this is apparently a proprietary language and there is no documentation, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

There ended up not being a solution that would work within the scripting confines of their code. Instead the response header was changed on the internal domain to use the internal response while looking for the external user attribute `uid`. This was able to solve the issue.